# Ubuntu 18.04 not booting/rebooting after fresh installation

Tags: boot, 18.04, shutdown, reboot

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and after I updated through the Software Update notification it isn't booting up/rebooting properly. I have press reset button multiple times for it to boot to desktop. If I shutdown the computer it doesn't shut down completely, as in everything inside the system is still running and all the lights, including the fans and the power switch.

My system in not in Dual Boot. I only installed Ubuntu 18.04. I am not using any Graphics Cards since Ryzen 2400G comes with a built in graphics (Vega 11).

I have attached results after running DMSEG in terminal. I hope that helps:
[DMSEG.txt via Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FKwfKbgqngdbiXttcII0KdswbWhj698dX6L7zYW4xcg)

My system:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 2400G (with Antec A40 Pro cooler)
- RAM: GKill Trident RGB 16GB (8GBx2)
- Motherboard: ASRock B450M Pro 4

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? You may want to create another / (root) of 25 or 30GB and install 18.10 (kernel 4.18) as it has newer kernel, just to see if that resolves issue. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseNotes & https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-2400g-may&num=1

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU is crashing. Check your video drivers.

You (may) have ECC memory, and ECC checking is disabled.

You (may) have wayland interfering with your GPU... so try this...

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.